# Find Duplicate Rows from Multiple Tables

Tags: sql, db2

I have following table structure:

USERS

Primary Key: UID

| uid | DOB |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1981-01-10 |
| 2 | 1981-01-10 |
| 3 | 1971-01-10 |

U_DETAILS

Primary Key: UID, SEQUENCE

Foreign Key: UID

| uid | sequence | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | Jack |
| 1 | 12 | Peter |
| 2 | 13 | Jack |
| 2 | 14 | Sam |
| 3 | 15 | Jill |
| 3 | 16 | Jill |

I'm trying to retrieve rows from USERS table where more than one users have same DOB and name.
So, in give dataset, UID 1 and 2 should be returned.

Could someone please help with devising a query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are content with the matching uids as a list, you can use aggregation:

```
select u.dob, ud.name,
       listagg(u.uid, ',') within group (order by u.uid)
from users u join
     u_details ud
     on u.uid = ud.uid
group by u.dob, ud.name
having count(*) > 1;
```

If you want separate rows, then I would suggest `exists`:

```
with ud as (
      select u.uid, u.dob, ud.name
      from users u join
           u_details ud
           on u.uid = ud.uid
     )
select uid, dob, uname
from ud
where exists (select 1
              from ud ud2
              where ud2.dob = ud.dob and
                    ud2.name = ud.name and
                    ud2.uid <> ud.uid
             );
```

EDIT:

Window functions are probably faster:

```
with ud as (
      select u.uid, u.dob, ud.name,
             count(*) over (partition by u.dob, ud.name) as cnt
      from users u join
           u_details ud
           on u.uid = ud.uid
     )
select *
from ud
where cnt > 1;
```

Comment: I used exists instead of "not exists" to get desired result. It works but runs very slow.
First query gives me following error:


SQLCODE=-4743, SQLSTATE=56038, SQLERRMC=null


Any idea why it gives error?

Comment: @NasirIqbal . . . The first method should be much faster.

Comment: @NasirIqbal   Speak with your Db2 for Z/OS DBA about configuring the target subsystem and your application binding to be able to use the `listagg` function.  The -4743 indicates application compatibility issue. See https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_11.0.0/apsg/src/tpc/db2z_applicationcompatibility.html